# Why is $\sqrt{ ( \sum (x_i^2) + x_{i+1}^2 ) ( \sum (y_i^2) + y_{i+1}^2 ) } \geq \sqrt{\sum (x_i^2)} \sqrt{ \sum (y_i^2) } + |x_{k+1} y_{k+1}|$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Without the restriction of character count constraints in the title, my question is more accurately to ask why it is the case that:
$\sqrt{ ( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i^2) +  x_{i+1}^2 ) ( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (y_i^2) +  y_{i+1}^2  ) } \geq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i^2)} \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{k} (y_i^2) } + |x_{k+1} y_{k+1}|$

I expand via FOIL to get:
$\sqrt{ \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i^2) +  x_{i+1}^2 \Big) \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (y_i^2) +  y_{i+1}^2  \Big) } \\
    = \sqrt{ \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i^2) \Big) \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (y_i^2) \Big) + \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (x_i^2) \Big) y_{i+1}^2 + \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{k} (y_i^2) \Big) x_{i+1}^2 + x_{i+1}^2  y_{i+1}^2}$

However, I'm unsure how to proceed from here to show that this is greater than or equal to $\sqrt{\sum (x_i^2)} \sqrt{ \sum (y_i^2) } + |x_{k+1} y_{k+1}|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$(A^2+a^2)(B^2+b^2)-(AB+ab)^2=A^2b^2-2AbBa+B^2a^2=(Ab-Ba)^2\geq 0.$$
Now let  $A:=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}$, $B:= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2 }$, $a:=|x_{k+1}|$, and $b:=|y_{k+1}|$.